# Render responsive image inside form fields programmatically

Tags: forms, 9

I am trying to figure out how to render a responsive image programmatically inside a form field. I am doing maintenance in a code on my current job, and sometimes there are form fields using the '#markup' property. Now I need to change all images to be responsive.

The code example:

```
$form['markup1'] = [
     '#markup' => '<div class="rating_reminder"><img src="'.file_create_url($order->campaign_id->entity->product_id->entity->image->entity->getFileUri()).'"><div>'
];
```

It is very hard to find anything explaining how to use responsive images that are in code in PHP.

I'll be very grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build render elements instead of HTML markup:

```
$form['markup1'] = [
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => ['rating_reminder'],
  ],
  'image' => [
    '#type' => 'responsive_image',
    '#responsive_image_style_id' => 'big',
    '#uri' => $order->campaign_id->entity->product_id->entity->image->entity->getFileUri(),
    '#attributes' => [
      'alt' => $order->campaign_id->entity->product_id->entity->image->alt,
    ],
  ],
];
```

Available render elements: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements